# Mysql filter duplicate records

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

My database has a field "STRING" which contains 3 values eg.:
When searching **like %Hugo M%** it produces 3 sets:

`Hugo M 
Hugo Me 
Hugo Meier`

Ist it possible to show **only one set** (Hugo Meier) with the best accordance ?

Comment: Define criteria for *best accordance* ?

Comment: So which one is the best?

Comment: is it with max characters in a field?

Comment: Use REGEX in query for better accordance..

Comment: The best sest would be "Hugo Meier" therefore i don't want to show the other ones.